# Ubuntu doesn't boot from the partition where it was installed via flash drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 from a flash drive. I already partitioned my drive which has Windows. I selected ex4 and formatted the disk space. It installed correctly, then it asked to restart. When I restarted, Windows was booted.

I can't find the 200 GB partition on Windows. When I try to boot again from the USB it went directly to the install screen. Where did the hard drive space go? How can I boot from the partition where I installed Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to AskUbuntu!

Because of the fact that you installed Ubuntu on an ext4 partition, Windows can't "see" it, and so it doesn't even recognize that the disk space is there. To have Windows see the partition it would have to be set up on a Microsoft format (FAT, FAT16, FAT32, NTFS). Ubuntu/Linux can see/read Windows formats, but Windows can only read Microsoft formats.

As for the reason that you can't start Ubuntu, did the computer do anything, or did it just boot directly to Windows. I guess I should ask, did you watch the computer the entire time it was booting?

GRUB, the Boot Loader that allows you to choose the OS you want to load (Windows, Ubuntu, etc.) only displays the choice for about 10-15 seconds before automatically booting the default choice. If you didn't watch the entire time and explicitly choose Ubuntu, it may have accidentally booted Windows instead of Ubuntu.

Best of Luck on solving your problem!

**EDIT:**Problem Solved!

Quote: @Shubhanyu Veldurthy

My problem is solved. I used boot repair disk from sourceforge. This is the link: http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd

Comment: Thank you, but my computer didn't go to the multi-boot screen.

Comment: Thank you, that helps some. Try holding down the `Shift` button while booting, sometimes this works to force GRUB to come up. If it does, respond here and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: Hey, thank you for responding. My problem is solved. I used boot repair disk from sourceforge.

This is the link: http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

Comment: How to remove that ubuntu from pc after attempting dual boot ?

Comment: Please copy/paste this answer as an answer to [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/708247/), Then dm me in [Island of castaway thoughts](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66387/island-of-castaway-thoughts) chatroom and I will upvote both of them.