# Ubuntu not showing in Windows 7 boot Manager

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 with a USB Flash Disk since I did not have a DVD Disc. I chose Install alongside Windows 7 and followed the process. After it had the popup screen with Continue Testing and Restart Now, I clicked Restart Now and removed the Flash Drive. The PC continued to boot to Windows 7 even though it was supposed to pass Grub first. I already tried re-installing Grub on the ext4 partition but still no luck and it ended up making my Windows 7 Boot Manager unusable too.

System:
Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit
4GB of RAM
AMD A4-5300 (with AMD Radeon 7480D IGP)
80 GB HDD Space (11.9 GB for Ubuntu)
Gigabyte GA-F2A75M-HD2

Tried to install: Ubuntu 13.04 amd64

Comment: Try [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).

Comment: Well, what do you mean of “re-installing grub on the ext4 partition”? Did you change the boot device from your harddisk to a specific partition when installing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ALL: Very similar question to this one http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/340045/ubuntu-doesnt-boot, though the messed-up Windows MBR is different.

@Andrei: Anyways, your problem is actually pretty common, try reading the link I mentioned above and this one: [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows). Hopefully they will help you solve your problem.